# How to model a followers system using TypeORM Entities

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm

I am creating an express app using typeORM to help map my objects to my database. I wish to create a followers system. I have a base layout of my User entity as shown below. However, this creates two join tables. I wish to have only one table that goes along the lines of 'user_follows_user', where userId_1 follows userId_2. I would like to be able to keep account of the number of followers and the number of following for each user as well. Is this possible? I'm still not fully understanding of what's even happening in my code.

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToMany, JoinTable, RelationCount } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @Column()
    bio: string;

    @ManyToMany( type => User, user => user.followers )
    @JoinTable()
    following: User[]

    @ManyToMany( type => User, user => user.following )
    @JoinTable()
    followers: User[]

    @RelationCount((user: User) => user.followers)
    followersCount: number;

    @RelationCount((user: User) => user.following)
    followingCount: number;
}
```

After running my code my database schema looked like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwgfS.jpg

As stated above I feel the need for only one table. Although I am open to other reasonable schemas for a followers system using this ORM.

Answer (score 3):

Your code could work, but keeping the followers in an array can get pretty ugly after a while.
Querying an array is harder and it takes longer too. And you can't keep some important information like the time of getting followed with your schema.
What you want to do is, make another Entity and keep the id of follower and the followed. Like this one:

```
import { Entity, Column, CreateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Subscription {

  @Column()
  userId: number;

  @Column()
  folowingId: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

}
```

getting the count of the followers or all of the followers can be done easily now by querying this entity.